# Redux - Arrays in my reducers not showing on first load and I'm receiving errors

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm new to Redux and React and I'm struggling with an issue for a while now. I have a reducer which contains a favorites array and another array storing the id's of the favorite movies.
Everything seemed to be working at first, but

**the problem** is when I open the app in another browser I receive error of *cannot read property filter / find of undefined, I get an error everywhere where I try to filter arrays of my reducer. What should I do differently ? I need to filter them because I want my buttons text to be 'Added' for the movies already in the watchlist. Is there something wrong with my reducer or is there another method I could use for filtering?

```
 const intitialState = {
      favorites: [],
      favIds: [],
      btnId: [],
      isFavorite: false,
      toggle: false,
    };
    
    const watchlistReducer = (state = intitialState, action) => {
      console.log(action, state);
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_WATCHLIST':
          return {
            ...state,
            favorites: [...state.favorites, action.payload],
            favIds: [
              ...state.favorites.map((movie) => movie.id),
              action.payload.id,
            ],
            btnId: action.payload.id,
            isFavorite: true,
            toggle: true,
          };
        case 'REMOVE_WATCHLIST': {
          return {
            ...state,
            favorites: [
              ...state.favorites.filter((movie) => movie.id !== action.payload.id),
            ],
            favIds: [...state.favorites.map((movie) => movie.id)],
            btnId: action.payload.id,
            isFavorite: false,
            toggle: false,
          };
        }
    
        case 'CLEAR_ALL': {
          return intitialState;
        }
    
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    
    export default watchlistReducer;
```

[image]

```
const MovieDetail = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { movie, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.detail);
  const { favorites, favIds } = useSelector((state) => state.watchlist);
  const [addFav, setAddFav] = useState([favorites]);
  //Toggle
  const [btnText, setBtnText] = useState('Add to Watchlist');
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useLocalStorage('toggled', false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([favIds]);

  const history = useHistory();
  const exitDetailHandler = (e) => {
    const element = e.target;
    if (element.classList.contains('shadow')) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
      history.push('/');
    }
  };

  const shorten = (text, max) => {
    return text && text.length > max
      ? text.slice(0, max).split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ')
      : text;
  };

  const toggleClass = () => {
    setIsToggled(!isToggled);
  };

  const changeText = (id) => {
    const check = favIds.filter((id) => id === movie.id);
    check.includes(id) ? setBtnText('Added') : setBtnText('Add to Watchlist');
  };

  const addFavHandler = (movie) => {
    const checkMovie = favorites.find((fav) => fav.id === movie.id);

    if (!checkMovie) {
      dispatch(addWatchlist(movie));
      setAddFav([...addFav, movie]);
      setBtnText('Added');
    } else if (checkMovie) {
      alert('Remove from Watchlist?');
      dispatch(removeWatchlist(movie));
      setBtnText('Add to Watchlist');
    } else {
      setAddFav([...addFav]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <StyledCard>
          <StyledDetails
            onChange={() => changeText(movie.id)}
            className='shadow'
            style={{
              backgroundImage: ` url("${bgPath}${movie.backdrop_path}")`,
              backGroundPosition: 'center center',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              backgroundBlendMode: 'multiply',
            }}
            onClick={exitDetailHandler}
          >
            <StyledInfo>
              <StyledMedia>
                <img
                  src={
                    movie.poster_path || movie.backdrop_path
                      ? `${imgPath}${movie.poster_path}`
                      : unavailable
                  }
                  alt='movie'
                />
              </StyledMedia>
              <StyledDescription>
                <div className='genre'>
                  <h3>{movie.title}</h3>
                  <p>
                    {movie.genres &&
                      movie.genres.map((genre) => (
                        <span key={genre.id}>{genre.name}</span>
                      ))}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className='stats'>
                  <p>
                    Release Date: <br />{' '}
                    <span>
                      {' '}
                      {movie.release_date ? movie.release_date : ` N / A`}{' '}
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Rating: <br /> <span> {movie.vote_average} </span>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Runtime: <br /> <span>{movie.runtime} min</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className='synopsys'>
                  <p>
                    {shorten(`${movie.overview}`, 260)}
                    ...
                  </p>
                </div>
                <button
                  className={btnText === 'Added' ? 'added' : 'btn'}
                  id={movie.id}
                  key={movie.id}
                  value={movie.id}
                  type='submit'
                  onClick={() => {
                    toggleClass();
                    addFavHandler(movie);
                  }}
                >
                  {btnText}
                </button>
              </StyledDescription>
            </StyledInfo>
          </StyledDetails>
        </StyledCard>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: The error seems to be originating in the `src/components/MovieDetail.js` file. Could you include the code for that file also?

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin Yes, I included it. Thank you for checking!

Comment: Here `const { favorites, favIds } = useSelector((state) => state.watchlist)`, `favIds` is initialized to be equal to `state.watchlist`. This means `state.watchlist === undefined` because it throws the error when the program runs. You need to see where and how you initialize & set `state.watchlist` which could be another reducer and or react component.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will look into it.